# How to write simple LISP macro to return output of a specified form (from the list of forms)?

Tags: macros, lisp

I am new to LISP and want to understand, how to write LISP macro code, which evaluates all forms but returns output of only one specified form, where the form to be returned could be specified inside macro or can be a user provided input.

I used following macro and it returns the output of the second form. but it doesn't seem correct, as it doesn't seem to evaluate the first form and I would like to specify which of the two forms to evaluate.

(defmacro testcode () (+ 3 4) (+ 5 6))

(macroexpand-1 (testcode))

11
NIL

Comment: You are supposed to put some effort in finding an answer. Best if the question contains actually code.

Comment: Rainer, I appreciate your feedback. I have added simple code that I was working with. Reason I am struggling is because I am getting a desired output, which is the output of the second form but I am certain that it isn't right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would then recommend to read a bit about the basics of Lisp and then macros. Here is a beginner introductory Lisp book: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/  Free for download. Chapter 14 then explains macros.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are syntactical abstractions or syntax sugaring. `testcode` does it's calculations in macro expansion time and thus you cannot expect the forms to be calculated more than once and `(testcode)` is synonymous with the "code" `11`. To illustrate that lets give it side effects:

```
(defmacro testcode ()
  (print "expanding testcode")
  (+ 3 4)  ; dead code. Never gets used
  (+ 5 6)) 

(defun test ()
  (testcode))
; prints "expanding testcode"

(test)
; ==> 11 (doesn't print anything)

(test)
; ==> 11 (still doesn't print anything, Why?)

(disassemble 'test)
; ==>
; 0     (const 0)      ; 11
; 1     (skip&ret 1)
```

So `test` literally is the same as `(defun (test) 11)`.

So what are macros? Well if you have written this and noticed there is a pattern:

```
(let ((it (heavy-cpu-function var)))
  (when it 
      (do-something-with-it it)))
```

You can say this is a thing I create syntax for:

```
(defmacro awhen (predicate-expression &body body)
  `(let ((it ,predicate-expression))
     (when it
       ,@body)))

(macroexpand-1 '(awhen (heavy-cpu-function var)
                  (do-something-with-it it)))
; ==>
; (let ((it (heavy-cpu-function var))) 
;   (when it 
;     (do-something-with-it it)))
```

So instead of writing the first you use `awhen` and Common Lisp changes it to the first. You are using a lot of macros since a lot of syntax in Common Lisp are macros:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(and (a) (b) (c)))
; ==> 
; (cond ((not (a)) nil) 
;       ((not (b)) nil) 
;       (t (c)))

(macroexpand-1 '(cond ((not (a)) nil) 
                      ((not (b)) nil) 
                      (t (c)))
; ==>
; (if (not (a)) 
;     nil 
;     (if (not (b)) 
;         nil 
;         (c)))
```